# Dismiss on Custom Dialog shows it again and then dismisses it

Tags: java, android, android-dialog

I have a custom dialog. I've made a dismiss button and when its pressed, the custom dialog closes and shows again and then closes.

Here you can find [a video demonstrating my problem](https://my.pcloud.com/publink/show?code=XZn2Qk7ZrnuTlEj8OV4ISHH7TL2vl05B1iWX).

Here's the code I have.

```
 switch (v.getId()){
    case R.id.settings_close:
        if(mDialog != null)
            mDialog.dismiss();
         break;
    case R.id.settings_button:
        mDialog = new Dialog(this, R.style.AppTheme);
        mDialog.setContentView(R.layout.view_settings);

        try{
            mDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(isNight?R.drawable.dark_blur:R.drawable.blur);

        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mDialog.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE);
        mDialog.show();
        mDialog.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(getWindow().getDecorView().getSystemUiVisibility());
        mDialog.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE);
        SetupBlurredView();
        break;
}
```

Comment: Any reason you are storing the dialog in the outer scope (likely the `class` instance given the `m` prefix)? Why not make it a local. That sort of pattern causes bugs left and right.

Comment: I think the UI elements behind the `AlertDialog` is being pressed when you're clicking the cross button. Can you please confirm that? Please add a log when the UI elements are clicked. So that you can understand the UI elements are not being pressed when you're closing the alert dialog.

Comment: Because i've implemented `View.OnClickListener`, making the `mDialog` local didn't solve the problem, i'm listening for dialog clicks instead of creating a new `OnClickListener` for each button.

Comment: @ReazMurshed I've tried to press 'Back' button instead of Close, which is in the dialog, i had the same result.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: I've figured out why, i have a custom theme for the dialog, in which i've added Fade In/Out animations, that whats causing the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
mDialog.cancel();
mDialog.dismiss();
```

Comment: what is this ? SetupBlurredView()

Comment: A method which blurs the background, i've deleted it because im already blurring the background.